What is this component - 8 legged inductor?
I am having trouble identifying this component. Pretty sure it must be an inductor of some sorts but I have never seen an inductor before with 9 legs (8 of which are used). The 8 used legs have continuity between them. I have measured the inductance with an LCR meter and posed the value between the legs (assuming that it is an inductor). Any help would be greatly appreciated.



What is this device supposed to do? Is it working or damaged?

Have you removed it from the board to take these measurements?

I have not removed it .. if the inductor was in series I didnt believe it was necessary .. but it turns out it may not even be an inductor

@wgthompson You cannot measure inductors or transformers in-circuit. At least unless you know what the circuit looks like of you can. So your measurements are useless and don't mean anything about the transformer.

even an inductor measurement in series would be useless?

@wgthompson If there are other paths of current between the points you measure than the transformer then you are not measuring the transformer and measurement is incorrect.

@Justme guess i need to invest in a heating pad/plate

@Justme without detracting from your comments or answer, which are perfect, we should give the OP credit for so meticulously attempting to measure the leg-to-leg inductances before asking the question.

It's not an inductor.
It's a transformer for a DC/DC converter, made by Epcos which is now a part of TDK.
Likely a custom order product for this specific product so likely no public data sheet available with the part number printed on it.

And the extra pin is to make sure that it can only be inserted with the correct orientation.
